# Database server down: file /dev/vda1 used up all diskspace

Tags: mysql, disk-space

My database server went down last night because there was no diskspace available. I checked what used up diskspace and it was 28GB by `/dev/vda1`

I have no clue what this is. The database all together will be a maximum of 1 GB diskspace, what is using up all this space?

When I start mysql, I get:

> error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

This is probably also because of the diskspace issue.

Hopefully someone can help me shortly. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer by me in a different thread might be of use to you? The command you want to keep an eye on is "df -h" which will give you usage by partition. You could monitor it on an ad-hoc basis and/or set up some sort of alert - Googling [this](https://www.google.ie/search?q=unix+alert+when+partition+is+getting+full&oq=unix+alert+when+partition+is+getting+full&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.10209j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) gave me several useful links which could be a lifesaver! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably found the reason, I made nightly backups to external server, but those were also stored on our server which had exceeded allowed disk usage. I didn`t understand /dev/vda1 at first, but I now get that is not a file but probably a partition or something like that.